# Change of Basis matrices check

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am working on change of basis and matrices and I wanted to make sure I was fully understanding them. 
Q: Suppose $M:W\rightarrow V$ is given by $M(\alpha\vec w_1+\beta\vec w_2+\gamma\vec w_3)=\alpha\vec v_1 + \gamma\vec v_2$. [B]=[$\vec v_1, \vec v_2$], [C]=[$\vec w_1, \vec w_2, \vec w_3$], [B']= [$\vec v_2, \vec v_1$], [C']=[$\vec w_1 +\vec w_3, \vec w_2 + \vec w_3, 2\vec w_3$]. Find $M_{[C][B]}, M_{[C'][B]}, M_{[C][B']}, and M_{[C'][B']}$

I've found $M_{[C][B]}$ to be $\quad
\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$

$M_{[C'][B]}$ to be $\quad
\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 2
\end{bmatrix}$

$M_{[C][B']}$ to be $\quad
\begin{bmatrix} 
0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$

I have work on how I made them if I need to include that please let me know. Do I seem to be on the right track? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right. And :
$$
M_{[C'][B']} =
\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 1 & 2 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

The starting point is that we can write:
$$
\alpha \vec w_1+\beta \vec w_2+\gamma\vec w_3=\alpha(\vec w_1+\vec w_3)+\beta(\vec w_2+\vec w_3)+\frac{\gamma-\beta-\alpha}{2}(2\gamma)
$$

Comment: Thank you! I just hadn't done the last one since I was checking the others. Wanted to make sure I was doing them correctly before continuing!

Comment: You are welcome! Don't forget to accept if you like :)